# How to reduce the time needed to export a view with 50k rows into a CSV file?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I am having a view with 50k records I want to export the view as CSV. I tried [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module but it takes around 20 min to export the data.

I have configured the view to use Batch export with **Segment size** 100.
I want to reduce the export time. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using Views (and Views data export), you may want to give it a try using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-mainter). If you do, I doubt it'd take 20 mins to complete such export (my bet is somewhere around 30 to 60 secs, at max ...).

To perform such export using Forena, just create a "report" to select (and sort, etc) the 50K records you want to export using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. And specify what kind of hyperlinks you want to make available for performing such "export". These hyperlinks correspond to various supported "formats", such as: CSV, PDF, XLS, XML, DOC, HTML ... (the "report designer" selects what the allowed/enabled export formats for a report are).

To get an idea of how that would look like, visit the [Customized Simple Table of States](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states_custom). Notice the links in it, such as "CSV" (upper right), which in this case would "export" the results in a CSV file.

Comment: @Vamsi - Basically you have to fetch your view's result programmatically and then send that through the Forena code. You could do this inside a form submit function you'd trigger from a submit button you added to your view using a preprocess function. I'd say.